# Convert EF LINQ method syntax to query syntax

Tags: c#, linq, linq-query-syntax

How would you write this ***exact same*** query using the LINQ query syntax?

```
var q2 = list.GroupBy(x => x.GroupId)
             .Select(g => g
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                 .FirstOrDefault());
```

I though this should work but it didn't:

```
var q1 = from x in list
         group x by x.GroupId into g
         from y in g
         orderby y.Date descending
         select g.FirstOrDefault();
```

Here's a test program if you want to play around with it:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var item = obj as MyClass;
        return item == null ? false : item.Id == this.Id;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<MyClass> 
    {
        new MyClass { GroupId = "100", Date=DateTime.Parse("01/01/2000"), Id = 1},
        new MyClass { GroupId = "100", Date=DateTime.Parse("02/01/2000"), Id = 2},
        new MyClass { GroupId = "200", Date=DateTime.Parse("01/01/2000"), Id = 3},
        new MyClass { GroupId = "200", Date=DateTime.Parse("02/01/2000"), Id = 4},
        new MyClass { GroupId = "300", Date=DateTime.Parse("01/01/2000"), Id = 5},
        new MyClass { GroupId = "300", Date=DateTime.Parse("02/01/2000"), Id = 6},
    };

    var q1 = from x in list
                group x by x.GroupId into g
                from y in g
                orderby y.Date descending
                select g.FirstOrDefault();

    var q2 = list.GroupBy(x => x.GroupId)
                    .Select(g => g
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                        .FirstOrDefault());

    Debug.Assert(q1.SequenceEqual(q2));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the let operator?

Comment: @frenchie no, I haven't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflector gives me the following:

```
var q2 = from x in list
         group x by x.GroupId into g
         select (
             from x in g
             orderby x.Date descending
             select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

which looks about right.

(As `Lazy` says, there's no *need* for `FirstOrDefault` in place of `First` as the groups won't be empty, but it doesn't *hurt*.)

Answer (score 3):

There is no `FirstOrDefault` operator in comprehension query syntax (if items are grouped, then at least one item will present in group, so you need `First`), but other stuff is translated like this:

```
var q1 = from c in list
         orderby c.Date descending
         group c by c.GroupId into g
         select g.First();
```

Trick is that items in group will be ordered, if you do grouping on ordered sequence. And voilà:

`q1.SequenceEqual(q2)` returns true

**BTW** according to LINQ Pad this query generates **exactly same SQL**, as query with nested `from x in g
 orderby x.Date descending
 select x`

**UPDATE** Also my bad - `First` will work with LINQ to Objects, or LINQ to SQL, but with LINQ to Entities you should use `FirstOrDefault`. And second note - these queries (my and with nested query) will generate same SQL for LINQ to SQL, but with EF my ordering is not applied.

Comment: +1. This does give the same result (and probably is more efficient), however, I was curious to know the exact functional equivalent, which this not.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I also was curious, thus verified both queries with LINQ Pad :)

Comment: The question was really about linq-to-objects. But I'm also looking at the SQL executed by Entity Framework using SQL Profiler, and it looks like EF by-passes the `orderby` (no ORDER BY in the executed SQL) -- so it makes no difference if you add `descending` or not

Comment: @ErenErsönmez yep, that what I was talking about in my last update